# rule engine with database support and rule modification API

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine, business-rules

I am trying for opensource rule engine where I can store the rules in data bases (mongodb or sql) also few APIs where I can modify the HA.

I came across these [rules opensources](https://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines) but rule engine like drool can be stored in drl file or csv , so I need to store the entire drl file or csv files in db and if I have to modify then needs to fetch entire db and store it back again,

so is there a better way to handle rules in DB and modify the rules whenever required with rest API..?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Drools already supports modifying and publishing rule changes in jar files using a maven repository for distribution.

Comment: Can you please help me how to  do this ? I did not see any way to modify and distribute it.

Comment: No I can't because that's not what this site is for. But if you read the documentation for Drools there are multiple ways of distributing and updating rules discussed. Eg. [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#kie-scanner-proc_packaging-deploying) or [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#_updating_a_container).